# maven dependency for org.springframework.test.web.server.samples.context.SecurityRequestPostProcessors

Tags: spring, maven, testing

What should I write in pom.xml to

```
org.springframework.test.web.server.samples.context.SecurityRequestPostProcessors
```

will appear in my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Add in pom.xml

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-snaspho</id>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

and use org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors for authorization request. See the sample usage at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2592)

Comment: Both M1 and M2 are also available at http://maven.springframework.org/milestone as of today.

Answer (score 0):

This project is not yet in Maven Central. You can check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc). You will need to add a `<repository/>` pointing to http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone in your `<repositories/>` section.

Why are you actually depending on code which is a "sample"...?

As stated on the page, you really shouldn't be using this. You should use `spring-test` instead as the code is integrated there.